# How do I find most frequent words by each observation in R?

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

*I am very new to NLP. Please, don't judge me strictly.*

I have got a very big data-frame on customers' feedback, my goal is to analyze feedbacks. I tokenized words in feedbacks, deleted stop-words (SMART). Now, I need to receive a table of most and less frequent used words.

The code looks like this:

```
library(tokenizers)
library(stopwords)
words_as_tokens <- 
     tokenize_words(dat$description, 
                    stopwords = stopwords(language = "en", source = "smart"))
```

The dataframe looks like this: there are lots of feedbacks (variable "description") and customers by whom the feedbacks were given (each customer is not unique, they can be repeated). I want to receive a table with 3 columns: a) customer name b) word c) its frequency. This "ranking" should be in a decreasing order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(tokenizers)
library(stopwords)
library(tidyverse)

# count freq of words
words_as_tokens <- setNames(lapply(sapply(dat$description, 
                                 tokenize_words, 
                                 stopwords = stopwords(language = "en", source = "smart")), 
                          function(x) as.data.frame(sort(table(x), TRUE), stringsAsFactors = F)), dat$name)

# tidyverse's job
df <- words_as_tokens %>%
  bind_rows(, .id = "name") %>%
  rename(word = x)

# output
df

#    name          word Freq
# 1  John    experience    2
# 2  John          word    2
# 3  John    absolutely    1
# 4  John        action    1
# 5  John        amazon    1
# 6  John     amazon.ae    1
# 7  John     answering    1
# ....
# 42 Alex         break    2
# 43 Alex          nice    2
# 44 Alex         times    2
# 45 Alex             8    1
# 46 Alex        accent    1
# 47 Alex        africa    1
# 48 Alex        agents    1
# ....
```

**Data**

```
dat <- data.frame(name = c("John", "Alex"),
                  description = c("Unprecedented. The perfect word to describe Amazon. In every positive sense of that word! All because of one man - Jeff Bezos. What an entrepreneur! What a vision! This is from personal experience. Let me explain. I had given up all hope, after a horrible experience with Amazon.ae (formerly Souq.com) - due to a Herculean effort to get an order cancelled and the subsequent refund issued. I have never faced such a feedback-resistant team in my life! They were robotically answering my calls and sending me monotonous, unhelpful emails, followed by absolutely zero action!",
                                 "Not only does Amazon have great products but their Customer Service for the most part is wonderful. Although most times you are outsourced to a different country, I personally have found that when I call it's either South Africa or Philippines and they speak so well, understand me and my NY accent and are quite nice. Let’s face it. Most times you are calling CS with a problem or issue. These agents have to listen to 8 hours of complaints so they themselves need a break. No matter how annoyed I am I try to be on my best behavior and as nice as can be because they too need a break with how nasty we as a society can be."), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: sorry, what's "x"? what't the function?

Comment: @k1rgas It's the argument of a lambda function which you typically use within a function. For example, if you want to know how many missing values you have for each column of a data.frame you would do: `apply(df, 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x))`. In this case, `x` is each column of the data.frame `df`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [**quanteda**](https://quanteda.io) as well as follows:

```
library(quanteda)
library(quanteda.textstats)
# define a corpus object to store your initial documents
mycorpus = corpus(dat$description)
# convert the corpus to a Document-Feature Matrix
mydfm = dfm( mycorpus, 
             tolower = TRUE, 
             remove = stopwords(),  # this removes English stopwords
             remove_punct = TRUE,   # this removes punctuation
             remove_numbers = TRUE, # this removes digits
             remove_symbol = TRUE,  # this removes symbols 
             remove_url = TRUE )    # this removes urls

# calculate word frequencies and return a data.frame
word_frequencies = textstat_frequency( mydfm )
```